# rxjs observable subscirbe pattern

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have the following angular component that I am refactoring to use observables instead of using `get` `set` and and private members:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FooService} from './foo.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-foo-component',
    templateUrl: './foo-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./foo-component.component.css']
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit
{
    private _loading: boolean = false;

    public fooForm: FormGroup;    

    public get loading(): boolean
    {
        return this._loading;
    }

    public set loading(
        value: boolean)
    {
        this._loading = value;
        if (value)
        {
            this.fooForm.disable();
        } else
        {
            this.fooForm.enable();
        }
    }

    constructor(
        private fooService: FooService)
    {
    }

    public onSubmitFooForm = () =>
        this.submitFooForm();

    private submitFooForm()
    {
        this.loading = true;

        this.fooService.fooFunction().subscribe((response) =>
        {   
            //navigate or some other custom action on success
            this.loading = false;
        }, () =>
        {
            this.loading = false;
        })
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.fooForm = new FormGroup();
    }
}
```

Refactored component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FooService} from './foo.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
        selector: 'app-foo-component',
        templateUrl: './foo-component.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./foo-component.component.css']
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit
{
    public fooForm: FormGroup;    

    public loading=new Subject<boolean>();

    constructor(
        private fooService: FooService)
    {
        this.loading.subscribe((isLoading) => this.toggleLoginForm(isLoading));
    }

    public onSubmitFooForm = () =>
        this.submitFooForm();

    private submitFooForm()
    {
        this.toggleLoading(true);   

        this.fooService.fooFunction().subscribe((response) =>
        {   
            //navigate or some other custom action on success
            this.toggleLoading(false);
        }, () =>
        {
            this.toggleLoading(false);
        })
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.fooForm = new FormGroup();
    }

    private toggleLoading(
        isLoading:boolean): void
    {
        this.loading.next(isLoading);
    }    

    private toggleLoginForm(
        isDisabled:boolean)
    {        
        if(isDisabled) 
        {
            this.fooForm.disable();
        } else 
        {
            this.fooForm.enable();
        }
    }    
}
```

Is there a way of calling the `toggleLoading` function automagically before and after the `fooService.fooFunction` gets executed instead of manually calling `toggleLoading` before and after invoking `fooService.fooFunction`

Comment: You can use `this.fooService.fooFunction().do(() => this.toggleLoading(true)).subscribe(...)`

Comment: thanks @martin I forgot to mention that I need to call the `this.toggleLoading(true)` before and after executing `this.fooService.fooFunction`. Is there any way of achieving the call after? I have updated the question to indicate this

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt use `.do` for "before", and call `this.toggleLoading(true)` in your subscribe for "after"

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt Then you can use also `finally` like this: `this.fooService.fooFunction().do(() => this.toggleLoading(true)).finally(() => this.toggleLoading(false)).subscribe(...)`

Comment: I have tried this and fooService.fooFunction() get executed before this.toggleLoading(true) should I not be doing this.toggleLoading first somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this, although, is not bad doing it manually if it is only in one place.

One way and preferred will do creating a new observable on the constructor that does that implicit 'toggleLoading' before and after the request. I have added to possible solutions, you can choose whatever you want:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FooService} from './foo.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-foo-component',
    templateUrl: './foo-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./foo-component.component.css']
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit
{
public fooForm: FormGroup;    

public loading=new Subject<boolean>();

private fooFunction$: Observable<any>;

constructor(
    private fooService: FooService)
{
    // 1: Observable create approach
    this.fooFunction$ = Observable.create(observer => {
                           this.toggleLoading(true);
                           this.fooService.fooFunction()
                                .finally(() => this.toggleLoading(false))
                                .subcribe(observer)
                       })

    // 2: Observable composition 'trick' approach
    this.fooFunction$ = Observable.empty()
                         .do(() => this.toggleLoading(true))
                         .concat(
                               this.fooService.fooFunction()
                               .finally(() => this.toggleLoading(false))
                         )

    this.loading.subscribe((isLoading) => this.toggleLoginForm(isLoading));
}

public onSubmitFooForm = () =>
    this.submitFooForm();

private submitFooForm()
{ 
    this.fooFunction$.subscribe((response) =>
    {   
        //Do whatever on success
    }, () =>
    {
        // Do whatever on error
    })
}

ngOnInit()
{
    this.fooForm = new FormGroup();
}

private toggleLoading(
    isLoading:boolean): void
{
    this.loading.next(isLoading);
}    

private toggleLoginForm(
    isDisabled:boolean)
{        
    if(isDisabled) 
    {
        this.fooForm.disable();
    } else 
    {
        this.fooForm.enable();
    }
}    
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried this and `fooService.fooFunction()` get executed before `this.toggleLoading(true)` should I not be doing `this.toggleLoading` first somehow?

Comment: Hi @TjaartvanderWalt, yes, what you are saying is true, I was missing the functionality of do operator.. lol. I have edited my post and added 2 possible solutions.